# Stop console.trace from automaticly expanding in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, logging, javascript, console

I'm working on a project where some library calls console.trace every refresh. Chrome then automaticly unfolds the trace, so that it takes over 20 lines on the console.

This takes too much space and I would much rather have it folded by default and only unfold when I click on it, like with litteraly everything else in the JS console.

Can this be done in Google Chrome, preferably without an extension? I have looked at all the option, but this seems to be impossible to disable.

Comment: You could maybe override `console.trace` with custom code (in the development environment only). I'm not sure if this approach can solve your problem, it's just an idea to explore.

Answer (score 3):

This is the subject of the bug-report from 2017
[Issue 677929: DevTools: console.trace has expanded stack trace by default](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=677929).

The bug was marked as fixed on 2018, then reported as being back
on 2019, marked as fixed again, reported as being back on 2019,
also reported by users as being still there on 2020 and 2021.

All these reports have not budged the bug status from
"Fixed (Closed)", so there is not much hope from
Chromium/Chrome.
You could try to open a new bug-report.

For a workaround, you could hide all messages from this source by
right-click on the little arrow in front of the trace and select
the option to hide all messages from this source.

For doing it in JavaScript, you could define your own
`console.trace`. This workaround is suggested in another
bug-report on the same subject from 2017 whose
Status is "WontFix (Closed)"
[Issue 697203: console.trace() expands automatically resulting in console bloat](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=697203) :

```
if(window.console && console.trace) {
    var oldTrace = console.trace;
    console.trace = function(msg) {
        console.groupCollapsed(msg || 'trace');
        oldTrace.apply(this);
        console.groupEnd();
    }
}
```

Comment: "so there is not much hope from Mozilla"
Do you mean Google?

Comment: @Black: Oups, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52595559/how-to-log-js-stack-trace-with-console-trace-but-keep-it-collapsed

```
console.groupCollapsed('name to show to identify trace');
console.log('additional data hidden inside collapsed group');
console.trace(); // hidden in collapsed group
console.groupEnd();
```

Comment: The trace is coming from in some JS library, so this solution would require me to override it, which would be possible I guess, however I wanted to know if it is possible to collapse trace log in browser by default, instead of changing the JS code.

Comment: Maybe console.error would work for you then? Assuming that you don't want to ship this to production, and only want to see the traces temporarily. Granted, that filtering could become not very simple, but for that you can add a unique string to the start of your log, and filter that in or out.

Comment: This wouldn't work with trace logs from jquery migrate... there should be some overriding code config to add to our own scripts. maybe something like `console.trace.autoExpand(false);` Migrate just clutters the console with expanded traces